# «S'il vous plaît merci» est-il impoli?

Tags: usage, politesse

Je rencontre parfois des gens qui lancent une demande à la ronde et concluent en disant « s’il vous plaît merci ! », par exemple :

> *Quand vous videz la cafetière, ce serait bien que vous en prépariez une nouvelle, s’il vous plaît merci !*

J’y comprends qu’ils expriment davantage un ordre qu’une proposition, puisqu’ils nous offrent un merci avant même que nous ayons fait quoi que ce soit, ce qui me laisse présumer que l’on croit avec assez de confiance qu’il *« nous plaira »*.

J’hésite tout de même quant à la courtoisie de l’expression. Le plus souvent, la demande semble légitime et l’on voit mal comment les gens se plaindraient d’une demande aussi simple à accomplir et aussi facile à justifier. D’un autre côté, il existe sans doute des empêchements occasionnels qui justifient qu’une fois de temps en temps, la cafetière se retrouve vide sans qu’il y ait eu malice, et la demande ne fait que réprimander publiquement une personne qui pour une raison ou pour une autre a causé une (courte) rupture dans la disponibilité du café, ce qui est un dommage franchement mineur ne justifiant pas forcément ce genre d’opprobre.

Quelle est l’expérience et la perception personnelle des gens sur cette expression ? Est-ce correct ou impoli ? Bénin ou inexcusable ?

---

<sub>Une possibilité qui m’est venue plus tard : se pourrait-il qu’il y ait simplement ellipse, et que le remerciement soit pour l’attention portée au message, non pour la ou les futures réalisations de la demande ?</sub>

Comment: Je pense que vous avez raison de dire que le "merci" est pour l'attention que vous avez porté à l'interlocuteur. "Merci" signifierait alors "Merci de m'avoir écouté, j'ai terminé." Il me semble que l'on emploie parfois "merci" pour signifier poliment que quelque chose est terminé. Dans ce cas il faut modifier la ponctuation finale en "s'il vous plaît. Merci !"

Comment: Je ne crois pas avoir entendu d'utilisation avec ce type de ponctuation modifiée, mais c'est intéressant. L'entendez-vous vous-même parfois? Peut-être que pour éviter le quiproquo aurait-on tendance à dire *«s'il vous plaît et merci de votre attention»*? Il me semble au moins qu'une telle utilisation, si je l'entendais, ne me causerait pas autant de questionnement sur la façon de comprendre le message. Il y aurait moins de doutes sur l'humeur de la personne.

Comment: J'interprète toujours le "s'il vous plaît merci" de cette manière. Je pars du principe que l'interlocuteur a eu l'intention de dire "s'il vous plaît. Merci !" mais qu'il n'avait plus assez d'énergie pour marquer clairement le point d'exclamation final. Pour quelqu'un qui utilise cette expression, il me semble que l'habitude doit lui faire penser que l'intonation est superflue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je dirais que ça dépend du contexte et sans doute effectivement de la ponctuation, mais que les deux sont courants.

Dans votre exemple c'est effectivement un reproche évident. Dans un autre cas ce pourrait être un merci de politesse :

> Mesdames, Messieurs, veuillez rejoindre vos sièges s'il-vous-plaît, merci.

Dans les deux cas, j'interprète plus facilement le "merci" comme "merci d'avance" que comme "merci de m'avoir écouté".

Comment: Très bon, cet exemple des sièges (en avion, je présume). On vous demande poliment de bien vouloir respecter les règles que l'on se doit de vous imposer, et on vous remercie de votre collaboration, plutôt que de vous de menacer les récalcitrants de conséquences légales. Ça aide au maintien d'un dialogue sain.

Comment: Le *merci* juste après le *svp* peut être utilisé pour vous imposer quelque part à rendre le service qui vous est demandé puisque vous en êtes déjà remercié ! *Tu peux t'en occuper, merci* laisse peu de choix. Le *Merci de votre attention* lève l’ambiguïté.

Answer (score 6):

Oui « s'il vous plait merci » sans interruption entre les deux formules de politesse risque fort d'être interprété comme trop direct.

Je recommanderais :

> [ S'il vous plait, ] si vous videz la cafetière, merci d'en préparer une nouvelle !

Comment: Êtes-vous ou avez-vous été exposé à ce genre d'expression? Certains l'ont-ils utilisé de façon plus digeste que d'autres? Je suis assez d'accord avec vous quant à l'analyse simple des mots, mais l'analyse du ton ou des circonstances *(demande bénigne ou requête difficile ou sujette à discussion)* m'intéresse aussi. Votre position est-elle immuable dans toute la gamme des utilisations?

Comment: Oui, j'ai déjà entendu cette expression.C'était le plus souvent par des adultes s'adressant à des enfants, le « merci » immédiat coupant court à toute contestation/discussion. S'il y a une pause avant « merci », la formule est beaucoup plus acceptable.

Comment: Je me demandais si des adultes agissaient parfois ainsi vis-à-vis d'enfants. Je n'ai pas été élevé de cette manière et maintenant que je suis adulte, je ne l'ai pas adoptée non plus, mais j'imagine que des enfants exposés à ce genre d'attitude deviennent des adultes plus ou moins immunisés à la rudesse possible de l'expression, et peuvent donc l'utiliser de manière un peu nonchalante, sans y voir à mal. Ou alors, comme dans l'exemple des sièges d'une autre réponse, on peut penser à un professeur avec un groupe d'enfants: il est parfois important que les consignes soient promptement suivies.

Comment: L'intonation et le contexte influent bien sûr beaucoup sur la sévérité et la rudesse de l'expression.